# Object in Javascript undefined when calling a method

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm building a game similar to the Chrome dinosaur in Vanilla JS. To animate the obstacles I have created a class Obstacle, which stores their position and size, and defines a method that changes the position.

```
var Obstacle = function (type, w, h, sprite) {
    this.h = h;                    // Obstacle height
    this.w = w;                    // Obstacle width
    this.x = 600;                    // Starting horizontal position
    this.y = GROUND - this.h;           // Starting vertical position
    this.type = type;
    this.sprite = sprite;
    this.speed = -4;

    this.move = function () {
        this.x += this.speed;
    }
}
```

These are stored inside an array, defined as a property of a different class:

```
var ObstacleBuffer = function () {

    this.bufferFront = [];

    this.createObstacle = function () {
        this.bufferFront.push(this.createBox());
    }
    // Obstacle creators
    this.createBox = function () {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) return new Obstacle ("box1", OBSTACLES.box1.w, OBSTACLES.box1.h, OBSTACLES.box1.sprite);
        return new Obstacle ("box2", OBSTACLES.box2.w, OBSTACLES.box2.h, OBSTACLES.box2.sprite);
    }

    //Obstacle animation
    this.animateObstacle = function () {
        this.bufferFront[0].move();
    }
}
```

When running this an error pops up:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'move' of undefined.
```

I have logger the content of `this.bufferFront[0]` and it correctly show the `Obstacle` stored inside it.

I have also tried assigning `this.bufferFront[0]` locally to a variable and then tried to call the method from there. The data stored is correct but the error pops up whenever trying to access `Obstacles` methods or properties.

Any ideas ? Thank you very much.

**EDIT -** I have reviewed the code as per your suggestions and the problem seems to be at the point where I'm calling the function. Before generating the obstacles I am preloading a series of images and only generating obstacles once these have load:

```
this.loadWhenReady = function () {
        if (self.resources.isLoadComplete()) {
            self.sound.load(self.resources.list.sfx);
            drawGround();
            this.obstacles.createObstacle();  // <--
            self.startGame();
            return;
        } else {
            setTimeout(self.loadWhenReady, 300);
        }
    }
```

And this is called in:

```
setTimeout(self.loadWhenReady, 300);
```

Of course const `self = this` has been defined before.

Everything seems to move forward when the method is called outside the `SetTimeout`.

Why is this happening though ? And is there a way of solving this while calling the method in there ?

**SOLVED -** As @Bergi and @Jaime-Blandon mention it was a context problem. Calling the method from outside the setTimeout loop or using `self.obstacle.createObstacle()` instead of `this.obstacle.createObstacle()` did the trick and solved the issue.

Comment: "*When running this*" - please show us the code that runs these constructors and methods

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have in fact changed the way I was calling the method and it certainly ahd some results. I have edited my original post accordingly.

Comment: You're using `this.obstacles` instead of `self.obstacles` in `loadWhenReady`? Aso, where are you calling `animateObstacle`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply again! That was exactly the problem. I wasn't using ```self.obstacles```. In any case just to be safe, and since I didn't need to call the method from inside that particular loop, I moved it to an external line in the code: much cleaner and safer. I was thanks to your comment and trying @Jaime-Blandon suggestion that I was able to track the problem. I didn't know how to mark your comment as "valid solution" though. In any case, thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: It's weird though that this didn't cause an exception in `loadWhenReady`. Do you (accidentally) have a global (`window.`)`obstactles` variable?

Comment: Not global, but both of them are part of a larger class, ```Game```. So both ```function loadWhenReady``` and ```this.obstacles``` are part of the same conext in there? I'm pretty new to JS and still get lost in this.

Comment: No, `setTimeout` calls functions with `window` as the `this` context. That's why you had to use `self`, it does not implicitly refer to some `Game` instance.

Comment: Oh of course... No idea then... If you can think of anything please let me know... I'm still learning and any new information helps me lot :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this change on the ObstacleBuffer Class:

```
var ObstacleBuffer = function () {

    this.bufferFront = [];

    this.createObstacle = function () {
        //this.bufferFront.push(this.createBox());
        this.createBox();
    }
    // Obstacle creators
    this.createBox = function () {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) this.bufferFront.push(new Obstacle ("box1", OBSTACLES.box1.w, OBSTACLES.box1.h, OBSTACLES.box1.sprite));            
        this.bufferFront.push(new Obstacle ("box2", OBSTACLES.box2.w, OBSTACLES.box2.h, OBSTACLES.box2.sprite));
    }

    //Obstacle animation
    this.animateObstacle = function () {
        this.bufferFront[0].move();
    }
}
```

Best Regards!

Comment: Thanks for changing to an edit. Please explain why this would solve the problem in the question if you know

Comment: the previos return "new Obstacle..." just ended in its own context and the buffer after the instantation just run into an empty array, now you force the array to keep the obstacle in memory and the move method will be avaliable

Comment: Thanks for your response but after the changes the call to move() generates the same Error.

Comment: EDIT - I have made another run and this has certainly something to do with the context. In fact I changed the way I was calling to the method and it suddenly worked before breaking again. I have edited my original code accordingly.

Comment: "*you force the array to keep the obstacle in memory*" - this makes no sense at all. The code in your answer does nothing different than the one in the question.